# change date values in 1 list to ith date value from another list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a sequence of dates

```
daysList <- seq(as.Date('2016-12-29'),as.Date('2017-01-01'),by="days")
```

countList, a list with decremented value of daysList count from 0 to last value:

```
countList <- list()
for (i in (length(daysList)-1):0) {
res <- 0:i
countList <- append(countList, list(res))
}
```

finally another list is generated, days_decremented, this list assigns values of dates in daysList to countList.

```
days_decrement <- lapply(rev(seq_along(daysList)), tail, x=daysList)
```

I need to generate another list that changes values in days_decrement to repeat ith value in daysList.

So the result would be something akin to:

```
>daysCopy
[[1]]
[1] "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29"
[[2]]
[1] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30"
[[3]]
[1] "2016-12-31" "2016-12-31"
[[4]]
[1] "2017-01-01"
```

I have tried a plethora of lapply, rep_len and even tried looping through the main days_decrement loop, assigning [[i]][i] values to daysList[i] values and I am getting nowhere.

As usual I am missing an lapply implementation I think.

Comment: you mean something along the lines of `lapply(days_decrement, function(i)replace(i, i != i[1], i[1]))`?

Comment: hmm perhaps, it should repeat the ith element for the entire list index, I'm trying to put your code into a loop but it is returning NULL, argh! I must have looked through 50 lapply,list pages on google by now, the loop code is as follows

 t <- for (i in 1:length(daysList)){
  lapply(days_decrement,function(x) replace(x,x!=daysList[i],daysList[i]))
}

Comment: Oh so you want like a nested list were the first element would be the list created by my lapply above?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the case.

Comment: This? `lapply(days_decrement, function(i) lapply(seq(length(i)), function(j) replace(i, i != i[j], i[j])))`

Comment: That's not working, perhaps I mis-understood, the returning list should be the same as days_decrement except repeating the value of ith daysList, so first value of days_decrement should be 15  repeats of "2016-12-19, 2nd value should be 14  repeats of "2016-12-20" all the way to last value being 1 repeat of  "2017-01-13". I'm looking into nested lists functions now. I think your approach is somewhat in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm...not quite sure I understand. Maybe make the exmple you put in your question smaller and add your exact expected output

Comment: I made the example smaller and the exact output as needed as well

Comment: I think countList is not even needed here, for context I am trying to work out cohort analysis for users, there is a case when no users are present in some days so my ggplot graph becomes quite unsightly. To fix this I want to create the entire cohort with cohortDate (the output of this questions), countList (0 for day 1, 1 for day 2 etc..) and finally actual day (days_decrement). Using these 3 columns I unlist them , shove them into a data frame and then merging that dataframe with my output data putting 0 values for days that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, then one way to go is to replace all the dates of `days_decrement` with the first date, i.e.

```
lapply(days_decrement, function(i)replace(i, i != i[1], i[1]))

#[[1]]
#[1] "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29"
#[[2]]
#[1] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30"
#[[3]]
#[1] "2016-12-31" "2016-12-31"
#[[4]]
#[1] "2017-01-01"
```

However, if you want to do it directly from the `countList` and `daysList` only, then,

```
 Map(rep, daysList, lapply(countList, length)) 
 #or similarly Map(rep, daysList, lapply(days_decrement, length))

#[[1]]
#[1] "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29"
#[[2]]
#[1] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30"
#[[3]]
#[1] "2016-12-31" "2016-12-31"
#[[4]]
#[1] "2017-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of work, you can try using `purrr` package and fonctional programming. `map` function and its friends are "kind of like" `lapply` but they reveal more consistent and powerful at usage and syntax with pipes is very concise.

```r
# your input
daysList <- seq(as.Date('2016-12-29'),as.Date('2017-01-01'),by="days")

# using purrr for creating your two lists
library(purrr)

# creating another kind of countlist
countList <- 1:length(daysList) %>% map(~.x:length(daysList))
countList
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3 4
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4

days_decrement <- rerun(length(daysList), daysList) %>% 
  map2(countList, ~.x[.y])
days_decrement
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2016-12-29" "2016-12-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-01-01"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-01-01"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "2016-12-31" "2017-01-01"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "2017-01-01"

# creating the one you asked
daysCopy <- map2(daysList, length(daysList):1, rep)
daysCopy
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29" "2016-12-29"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30" "2016-12-30"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "2016-12-31" "2016-12-31"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "2017-01-01"
```